# Text search within an HTML document within Jackrabbit

Tags: java, search, jackrabbit, jcr

I am using jackrabbit for storing HTML files.'I want to build a simplest search engine possible where i send a text String as a parameter and it returns me the list of html pages on a particular node which have that text in them.
What is the best possible way to implement a HTML file search within jackrabbit.

Comment: Have you read the chapter on querying yet? http://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html

Answer (score 1):

Jackrabbit by default uses lucene for its index. So you already have a rather good search engine in place. You probably only need to tune the configuration:

- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Search
- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration